# symfony - dropdown menu doesn't select the option

Tags: symfony

I made a page on symfony to administrate some products with a dropdown menu linked to a category table.
The categoryid is well saved on the product, but the dropdown never select the good option, I don't find why.

Here is the category part in my class Dproduct :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=RCategory::class, inversedBy="products")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="categoryId", referencedColumnName="categoryId", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $categoryId;


public function getCategoryId(): ?RCategory
{
    return $this->categoryId;
}

public function setCategoryId(?RCategory $categoryId): self
{
    $this->categoryId = $categoryId;

    return $this;
}
```

here is my class RCategory:

```
/**


* RCategory
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="r_category")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class RCategory
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="categoryId", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $categoryId;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="categoryLib", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     */
    private $categoryLib;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"categoryLib"})
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=128, unique=true)
     */


    public function getCategoryId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->categoryId;
    }

    public function getCategoryLib(): ?string
    {
        return $this->categoryLib;
    }

    public function setCategoryLib(string $categoryLib): self
    {
        $this->categoryLib = $categoryLib;

        return $this;
    }
```

here is my buildForm function :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('categoryId', ChoiceType::class, [
            'mapped'  => false,
            'choices' => $options['choiceCategory'],
            'label'  => 'Catégorie'
        ])
        ->add('productLib', TextType::class, [
            'label'  => 'Libellé',
        ])
        ->add('Enregister', SubmitType::class)
    ;
}
```

And my choiceCategory function :

```
public function choiceCategory(){
    $choices          = [];
    $categories = $this->getCategory();
    foreach ($categories as $categorie) {
        $choices[$categorie->getCategorylib()] = $categorie->getCategoryid();
    }
    return $choices;
}
```

And finaly my controller :

```
$product = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('App:DProduct')
            ->findOneBy(array('slug' => $slug));
...

    $form = $this->createForm(productType::class, $product, array('choiceCategory'=>$categoryController->choiceCategory()));
    $form->handleRequest($request);
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
... Data is well saved ...
}


    return $this->render(
        'form/meuble.html.twig',
        array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'titlePage' => $titlePage,
            'product' => $product
        )
    );
```

Does anyone see where is the problem ?
Thanks,
Best regards,
Matthieu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an unmapped field, therefore it won't set any data based on the product you are editing.

You can set the data with de `data` option

```
$product = $builder->getData();
...

->add('categoryId', ChoiceType::class, [
    'mapped'  => false,
    'choices' => $options['choiceCategory'],
    'label'  => 'Catégorie'
    'data' =>  $product->getCategory(),

])
```

U might be able to use a mapped field and use the [EntityType](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) instead of the ChoiceType to build the choices. Notice the [choice_label](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choice-label) and [query_builder](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#query-builder) options.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfect with EntityType :

            ->add('categoryId', EntityType::class, [
                'class'  => RCategory::class,
                'choice_label' => function ($category) {
                    return $category->getCategoryLib();
                }
            ])